# Free sofware or website with a WYSIWYG editor to build WebSites

Tags: web-development, html-editor, wysiwyg

I'm building a website that will host some community projects. I want to give to an user that knows nothing about HTML/CSS/JavaScript coding the ability to create some simple web pages using an external [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) website editor and the output of this external program will be uploaded to my website where I will host and show the contents.

I'm looking for something like wix.com, but wix does not solves my problem because I have three additional requirements:

1. The user have to start the website using templates that I will provide. After the user has finished, I may be able to use the user website as a new template.
2. The user may use some components that will connect to my database. For example, one page may show an image that is stored in my database. So the user may look to one of my templates to learn how to do this.
3. When the user has finished the website, I need that the program exports all html/css/js so the user can zip and upload it to me. (may be optional since the user can send me na URL and I can look and retrieve all contentes of a web page).

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Would you rather it web based or pc software based?

Comment: If PC based, which operating system. Also, must it be free, or will you pay (and, if so, what is your budget)?

Comment: https://webflow.com/ and https://bootstrapstudio.io might be worth looking at. webflow has a plan level that allows you to export the code and bootstrap studio is a buy once application, both offer WYSIWYG like interfaces. you'd have to look into each one for the templating and database integration though